# Ruby: Instance variables vs local variables

Tags: ruby

I'm learning Ruby right now, and I'm confused as to why I can refer to an instance variable without the @ sigil, which would make it a local variable too. Surely the following code shouldn't work as it does:

```
class Test
  attr_accessor :variable
  def something
    variable
  end
  def something2
    @variable
  end
  def something3
    self.variable
  end
end

y = Test.new
y.variable = 10
puts y.something  # => 10
puts y.something2 # => 10
puts y.something3 # => 10
```

I'd have expected `y.something` to return nil. Why do local variables and instance variables point to the same location? I'd have expected `@variable` and `variable` to have been two discrete variables.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In the code you posted, `variable` is **not** a local variable. It is a **method call** to the instance method named `variable`, which was defined by:

```
attr_accessor :variable
```

This is a shorthand for the following method definitions:

```
def variable
  @variable
end

def variable=(value)
  @variable = value
end
```

Note that Ruby does not require parentheses `()` for a method call, so distinguishing between a local variable and a method is not always easy.

Compare your code with:

```
class Test
  attr_accessor :foo

  def example1
    foo = nil  # 'foo' is now a local variable
    foo
  end

  def example2
    foo        # 'foo' is a method call
  end
end

x = Test.new
x.foo = 10
x.example1  # => nil
x.example2  # => 10
```

Comment: That makes so much more sense!

Comment: Nitpick: it is perfectly possible to distinguish between a local variable reference and an argumentless receiverless message send without knowing which methods exist. In fact, it *has* to possible, because the distinction is made statically at parse time, while methods get defined dynamically at runtime. IOW: when the distinction is made, the methods don't even exist yet. Replace your `foo = nil` with `if false; foo = 42 end` to see exactly how it works.

Comment: You're right; always possible, but not always easy for a human. I've adjusted my answer to be more correct.

Comment: Technically, I believe your `foo = nil` line is calling the `foo=` method.  If you change your example to use an `attr_reader`, it would be more correct, but then `x.foo = 10` would break.

Comment: @bheeshmar: No, `foo = nil` will never call a method. You have to use `self.foo = nil` to accomplish that.